# Add stroke effect to DIV border

Tags: html, css

I need to create a HTML div with custom border. According to what the designer told me, the border has a radius of 3px and stroke of 8px, color f7f7f7 and position outside

What I have so far is:

```
div#content {
    padding                 :   10px 20px;
    border-style                :   solid;
    border-width                :   8px;
    border-color                :   #F7F7F7;
    -webkit-border-radius       :   3px;
    -moz-border-radius          :   3px;
    border-radius               :   3px;

}
```

I really don't know what the stroke effect is and how to do it with css.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stroke basically means outline or border - this is the professional name of it. your code seems fine. didn't it work?

It works in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8cKTc/). it creates a thick, light grey border with a little bit of rounded corners.

also, you can use shorthand: `border: 8px solid #f7f7f7;`

Comment: ok, thanks for the answer, at this time i don't have the design yet. But I wasn't sure what's the stroke effect. I suposse my code is fine then

Answer (score 0):

i understand 'stroke' as outlined , like usually said for a text effect.
I would go ,since outline isn't  friendly with radius:

```
div {
    border:solid; /* no info for size nor color yet */
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 8px #f7f7f7;
    border-radius:3px; /* prefix not needed anymore */
}
```

Answer (score -3):

What you are looking for is border: dashed;
If the designer said stroke, chances are they mean dashed.
I've updated Yotam's fiddle

```
border-style : dashed;
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8cKTc/2/)

Comment: Adding a stroke to a box/object in any design program simply creates a solid border. IMHO Yotam has it right.